# How to build a triangle with same area as a given square, if two of its sides are known?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area

> Build a triangle with same surface as a given square, if two of its sides are known.

#### Progress

I know that it suffices to build a rectangle with area twice the area of the square.  Once I build a rectangle, I choose one side  to be one side of the triangle. Then I choose wherever on the parallel side an apex of the triangle.  Because, the area will be: $$\text{base}\cdot \text{height}/2 =2l^2/2= l^2 = \text{area of the square}$$

Comment: Given a square, and a side, you know how to construct a rectangle of the same area as the square with one side being that given side, right?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Gina. I don't understand the above explanation. In the problem'context, two sides of the square are known, no? I didn't understand it well

Comment: If you have the square, do you know how to construct a rectangle when one side of the rectangle is known?

Comment: The wording is sloppy: I think the intention here is two sides *of the triangle* are known, since two sides of a square would be pretty boring and a little nonsensical...Thus, it seems to be a question about the angle between the two given sides. Trigonometry?

Comment: Yes, DonAntonio, two sides of the triangle are known. I will add another tag.

Comment: I understood the question correctly. I am giving the asker a hint: construct a rectangle first, then finally the triangle. The word "build" here suggest compass and straightedge. If it's just a trig problem it would be too trivial I think.

Comment: And, the rectangle area = 2 * the square area , right? Then, construct a diagonal => the triangle which have the area = 1/2 * the rectangle area = the initial square area ?

Comment: That work too. Then you would first have to double the square (double it into a rectangle is fine, no need to remain square), then construct a rectangle with one side being a known side of the triangle. Then you don't have to take the diagonal: there is no guarantee that the diagonal is of the correct length. Instead, simply construct a new vertex so that the apex is on the same line as the side of the rectangle.

Comment: @Gina That's right.  Please make it an answer.

Comment: Let me show you if I'm clear with your good tips: I build a rectangle. I choose one side ( = 2*side of the square ) to be one side of the triangle. Then I choose wherever on the parallel side an apex => the triangle. Because, the area will be: $base*height / 2$ =$2l^2/2$= $l^2$ = the square area

Comment: Unfortunately, your construction do not guarantee that the side of the triangle is of the correct length. You need an intermediate conversion, where you "resize" the rectangle so one side of the rectangle match the required length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given any rectangle $ABCD$ and we want to construct a rectangle with the same area and one side being a fixed length $l$. We do as follow: put a point $E$ on the ray $AB$ such that $AE=l$. Draw $DE$. Then draw a line through $B$ parallel to $DE$ and let it intercept the line $AD$ at $F$. Then $AE$, $AF$ would be the length of the side of the rectangle. Prove this using similar triangle.

So how to use that to do the problem? Let $a,b$ be the required length of 2 side of the triangle. First, double the square by making a copy of itself, so you get a rectangle. Now using the method above, acquire a rectangle $ABCD$ of the same area as twice the square, where $AB=a$. Let the circle centre $A$ radius $b$ intercept the line $CD$ at $E$. Then $ABE$ is the required triangle. This is because the height of the triangle with apex $E$ is the same as $AD$ and we already know the rectangle is twice the original square.

In fact, the fact that you started with a square is completely inconsequential.

Comment: The circle centre A radius = B??

Comment: How did you start to note the ABCD rectangle? $A$ in the top left apex and $B$ in the top right apex and so on... Or?

Comment: It does not matter whether one is top right or top left or anything. And the $B$ was a typo it's $b$ the length of the side of the triangle you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the area of square and $a,b$ sides of triangle we need the angle $C$ of triangle such that $$S=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin C$$from above it is$$C=\arcsin\frac{2S}{ab}$$